# Why setter methods don't update Object?

Tags: java, arraylist, set, setter

I want to update the Contact object, which has 2 fields - name & phoneNumber.
Unfortunately I don't know why setter methods don't work.

Firstly I tried with the `#1` version of updateContact() method - code below.
I think that it may have something with updating reference of an object, not the object itself? I'm not sure.

If anybody could explain me that, why the code with setters doesn't work... - I mean it updates the 'contact' within the function, but doesn't update contact in the ArrayList - contacts.

The `#2` method works, but I'm not sure if it's a good idea/solution - well, it works... but I think that with setters it should work as well.

## 1

```
    public void updateContact(String name) {

        Contact contact = findContact(name);

        System.out.print("Enter new name: ");
        contact.setName(scanner.nextLine());

        System.out.print("Enter new phone number (9 numbers): ");
        contact.setPhoneNumber(scanner.nextLine());
    }
```

## 2

```
    public void updateContact(String name) {

        Contact contact = findContact(name);

        String replaceName;
        String replaceNumber;

        System.out.print("Enter new name: ");
        replaceName = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter new phone number (9 numbers): ");
        replaceNumber = scanner.nextLine();

        Contact replace = new Contact(replaceName, replaceNumber);

        contacts.set(contacts.indexOf(contact), replace);
    }
```

findContact method

```
    public Contact findContact(String name) {

        Contact currentContact = null;

        for (Contact contact : contacts) {
            if (contact.getName().equals(name)) {
                currentContact = new Contact(name, contact.getPhoneNumber());
            }
        }

        return currentContact;
    }
```

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: You're just creating a new `Contact` object that's only in scope within the method. It looks like you're shadowing a variable

Comment: Use `currentContact = contact;` so that the returned object reference is the one in the list.

Comment: Everything works, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your findContact() method is not returning a reference to a Contact object in the ArrayList, instead you are creating a new object with a copy of the data and then returning it.

Change it as follows and your first approach should work:

```
public Contact findContact(String name) {

    Contact currentContact = null;

    for (Contact contact : contacts) {
        if (contact.getName().equals(name)) {
            currentContact = contact;
            break;
        }
    }

    return currentContact;
}
```

Comment: Of course, the `findContact` method was likely explicitly coded to return a copy, so a caller couldn't update the contact without the class knowing about it, e.g. to apply validation constraints, so changing the method to not return a copy is likely with wrong thing to do. Instead, the class should implement a `updateContact(String name, String phoneNumber)` method.

Comment: @Andreas I'm not sure that I totally understand. Shouldn't he return a reference to the object in the ArrayList to be able to update it even if he adds the method to the class for validation purposes? or Are you favouring returning a copy then updating it then following his second approach, for example, to update the ArrayList?

Comment: The purpose of setter methods, instead of public fields, is to allow the class to add logic when a value it set, e.g. for validation or to calculate derived values. The `contacts` list, and everything in it, is managed by the given class, so to fully (deeply) encapsulate the data, the class should return copies of any mutable objects. E.g. if the class wanted to ensure that names are unique, it cannot allow a caller to change the name of a `Contact` object directly.

Comment: ... Or if the class decided to change implementation from `List` to a `Map`, keyed by `name`, then a caller that updated a `Contact` object would not cause the `Map` to be updated, breaking the code. --- Of course, you wouldn't have these issues if `Contact` was immutable, which is why immutable classes are so desired. And you wouldn't care if you trust the caller to not update the object, or if you knew that the class would never need to replace `List` with `Map`, but since you can't know the future, defensive programming states to return copies.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for your detailed explanation. My knowledge about best programming practices is still quite limited, so I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Complete solution by using different class Name..
Above solutions doesn't Continued old Data..

```java
System.out.println("Enter Id OF student");
String inputId = sc.next();
for(Student std : list ) {
   if(std.getId().equals(inputId)){
     Student newdata = std;
     System.out.println("Enter New Marks and Phone Number:");
     Student update = new Student(newdata.getId(),newdata.getCourse(),sc.nextDouble(),sc.next(),newdata.getEmail());
     list.set(list.indexOf(newdata), update);
         break;
  }
}
```